How to create a convenient Optimizer API for Linear Regression Model Optimizer?
My goal is to create a Linear Regression model without a framework. However, I am trying to follow PyTorch. One part of it is a convenient class Optimizer API.
So the usage will be like this
output = model(input)
loss = loss_fn(y_prediction, y_actual)

The problem is this equation y = w * x + b, the derivative of w and b is different.

d/dw (ŷ - y)² = 2 * (w * x + b - y) * w.
d/db (ŷ - y)² = 2 * (w * x + b - y) * 1.

class Optimizer:
    def execute(self) -> int:
        pass
    
class GradientDescent(Optimizer):
    def execute(self, w: int, x: int, b: int, y: int) -> int:
        # 1. d/db (ŷ - y)²
        #    d/db (w * x + b - y)²
        #         2 * (w * x + b - y) * 1
        # 2. d/dw (ŷ - y)²
        #    d/dw (w * x + b - y)²
        #         2 * (w * x + b - y) * w
        return 2 * (w * x + b - y) * w

